# /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a: error adding symbols: Bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status error: command 'gcc

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

Hi I'm compiling `mod_wsgi` in `virtualenv` with `python3.6` and `apache2.4`.

I already have another `virtualenv` with `python3.5` and `mod_wsgi` works.
Compiling in my new `virtualenv` with `python3.6` with:

```
./configure --with-python=/home/fgthct/.virtualenv/djangodev/bin/python
```

This generates the `Makefile`. When I run `make`, I finally get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct 'can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a: error adding symbols: Wrong value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1.
```

I reiterate that I already have another `virtualenv` with `python3.5` and it works.

Thanks in advance to those who want to help me.

Fgthct

Comment: You're trying to build a shared object using code that wasn't compiled to be in a shared object (*Python3.6*'s library). Either rebuild your *Python3.6* with `-shared`, either instruct *VEnv* not to create shared objects (don't know if possible / how).

Comment: The option you need to the ``configure`` script when installing Python is ``--enable-shared`` not ``-shared``.